# How to position background image in a button

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS:

```
.physButton:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../theImages/ste.png") no-repeat;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 52px;
    /*margin-left: 10%;*/
}
.locButton:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../theImages/loc.png") no-repeat;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 52px;
    /*margin-left: 10%;*/
}
.mwmButton:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("../theImages/loc.png") no-repeat;
    height: 38px;
    line-height: 38px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 52px;
    /*margin-left: 10%;*/
}
button {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background: #eee;
    color: #515151;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 21px 34px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.21, rgb(203,203,203)), color-stop(0.58, rgb(227,226,226)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(203,203,203) 21%, rgb(227,226,226) 58%);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3) /* glass edge */, inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5) /* top highlight */, inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5) /* bottom shadow */;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 -3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
button::-moz-focus-inner, a.button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}
button:hover, a.button:hover {
    background: #cbcbcb;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button:active, a.button:active {
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 22px 34px 20px; /* Bump down text */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.3), inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5), inset 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: none;
}
.locButton {
    background: #e1001a;
    color: #fff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.21, rgb(192,0,22)), color-stop(0.58, rgb(226,0,26)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(192,0,22) 21%, rgb(226,0,26) 58%);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.locButton:hover {
    background: #cb0018;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.locButton:active {
    background: #ae0014;
}
.mwmButton {
    background: #E05A00;
    color: #fff;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0.21, rgb(192,63,0)), color-stop(0.58, rgb(224,74,0)));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(192,63,0) 21%, rgb(224,74,0) 58%);
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
.mwmButton:hover {
    background: #CA7700;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.mwmButton:active {
    background: #AC6900;
}
```

which displays the following:

[image]

How do I modify the above code the the images aligns to the left and the text aligns to the right as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Will you post all your html and css in a jsfiddle?  The solution may be more than just css changes.

Comment: Why are you hiding your code with "<!--"?

Comment: One solution would be to use two SPAN elements inside each button. Put the image in one and the text in the other and then set the SPAN elements to inline-block level and divide up the space.

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/2CHQH/

Comment: @Diodeus It is called from a stylesheet file and the hiding the code ensure it doesn't get displayed in older browser that doesn't support css (which I think is in the 0.00000000000001%) ;)

Comment: @HarveyA.Ramer Would you please give me an example?

Comment: used your fiddle, but fixed the icon height and width same. here is the updated link. http://jsfiddle.net/2CHQH/

Comment: @KheemaPandey Thank you for taking the time but if you notice the texts are not aligned to right and the image is not aligned left. Instead it's like a stair going down.

Comment: @SiKni8, Yes, I am aware of that. The point I am making is there is not a single browser on the planet that still requires this. This has not been a requirement for 15 YEARS.

Comment: Thanks :) I will keep in mind.

Comment: @SiKni8 I've done a quick mock-up on a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/harveyramer/7MdYh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="mbLOnlyButtons">
    <button class="mwmButton" style="width: 95%;"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span><span class="text">My WESTMED</span></button>
    <div style="clear: both;"><br></div>
    <button class="physButton" style="width: 95%;"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span><span class="text">Physicians</span></button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button .text { width: 50%; display: inline-block; text-align:left;}
button .icon { width: 50%; display: inline-block; background: url("http://www.westmedgroup.com/images/HealthCareReformv2.jpg") top right no-repeat; }
```

This sets up two separate regions within your buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom picture, the space between image and text are different - just add a bit of padding right on the locButton and physButton `:before` pseudo elements until they align, you'll need 4-10px.

Answer (score 1):

Place a span around the text and give it a standard width that is big enough for all the buttons (lets say 100px). Now apply this css style:

```
width:100px;
text-align:right;
```

the icon will stay on the left (it's default place), and the text will allign